# Tables created form model db MS SQL server

Tags: sql-server

Long time I have not changed active database (like USE mydbname) and created bunch of tables into a master database I think. Ever since then when new databases are created these tables appears in it.

I think one of the four default databases (master, model, msdb, tempdb) works as model for new databases and therefore the "extra" tables must be stored somewhere. Based on this description, could you please advice me how to get rid of these tables in order to create new empty databases?

Comment: `use model; drop table dbo.tablename;`

Comment: It's `model`. `model` is used as the *model* for new databases

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the get the user tables in system database?

you can try this:

```
EXEC sys.sp_MSforeachdb @command1 = N'use ?;select ''?'', * from  sys.tables WHERE type=''U'' and is_ms_shipped=0'
```